# Pass an image as a variable (javascript, canvas)

Tags: javascript, html, variables, canvas

I have a function, `imageReader(image)`, that processes an image after it loads (id="bgImage" here). By writing `imageReader(this)`, I can have the image itself as a variable, which allows me to get its width, draw it, etc.

The thing is I want to be able to target any image in my page when I want to (and not depend on `onload="javascript:imageReader(this)")`, but `$('bgImage').load(function(){});` won't get me there. How can I target any image as a variable with my function? Thanks a lot!

```
<body>
    <canvas id="bg" width="0" height="0"></canvas>
    <img id="bgImage" src="img/logo.png" onload="javascript:imageReader(this);"></img>
</body>
```

A few things I do with my following function

```
   function imageReader(image) {
      var imgWidth=image.width;
      var imgHeight=image.height;
      myCanvasContext.drawImage(image,0,0);
   }
```

Comment: `javascript:` is useless in the `onload` attribute. So your problem is that `imageReader` is not called?

Comment: @FelixKling, thanks for your answer. Everything works fine. The thing is I want to not use the "onload" line in the html page but target the image from my script.js file, but I can't get to get the image as a variable for my imageReader() function. Targetting, I don't know, the src of the image would be easy, but I don't know how to target the image itself as it did when I used the onload="imageReader(this)".

Comment: have you tried doing `console.log(image);` to find out what's accessible.

Comment: you could use jquery for document ready and the selector.

Comment: Yes and it returned the whole <img id="bgImage" src="img/logo.png" onload="javascript:imageReader(this);"></img> thing. How can I pass all that as a variable from my script.js file? I'm using jQuery by the way

Comment: In jQuery it is basically the same:  `$('#bgImage').load(function(){ imageReader(this);});`

Comment: Ok thanks! I didn't work because I put the $('#bgImage').load(function(){ imageReader(this);}); in a document.ready(), which couldn't work. I put it out of the document.ready() and it now works.

Comment: Still can I do something like imageReader($('#bgImage'));? Because I want to be able to trigger the imageReader function when I want to, not only when the image loads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I didn't get your question 100% 
I think you have a difficulty to get Image object after the image got loaded right ? 
You could do that by check the image `complete` element with javascript 
first, declare a JS function to detect the image have been loaded or not : 
`var complete_load = function () {}`
then within the function get the element : 
`var the_img = document.getElementsById("bgImage");`
then, check it complete parameter, if not loaded yet, re-loop with `setInterval`:

```
if(the_img.complete){
   setInterval(complete_load , 200);
}
```

how about this ?